# How to Creating a Data Disk Image from an External Image File in Huawei Cloud Stack?

Tags: cloud, virtual-machine, virtualization, huawei-developers, huawei-cloud

I want to upload the VM image into the Huawei Cloud Stack, but I have no idea how to do it through Image Management Service(IMS). I have tried to read manuals ([Creating a Data Disk Image from an External Image File](https://support.huaweicloud.com/intl/en-us/usermanual-ims/ims_01_0215.html)), searched through the internet and YouTube, as it is relatively new product there is no any third party info how to do it. [I am stuck here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrOKH.png)